# how to set a value to the input with out using ngmodel in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

here i am using a typical input scenario where i can't use reactive/template form structure  and ngmodel already assigned to other task. now i want to set a default value to the input fields and if user wants he can change the change

is it possible

```
<input id="{{data.name}}" value="{{data.name}}"  type="{{data.type}}" [(ngModel)]="Edit[data.name]" class="form-control">
```

mainly my issue setting value to the input fields & if user wants then he may change value to the individual fields or setting value to dynamic **ngmodel**

Comment: `[(ngModel)]=" data.name"` Doing so you can set the value

Comment: " and ngmodel already assigned to other task. now i want to set a default value". The only way I know is give value to your variable "Edit[data.name]" (well I supouse yo have an object data with default values) You can use placeholder to see a message like "enter name"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="text"  [value]="data.name"/>
```

if you still need to way binding

```
<input type="text"  [value]="test"  [(ngModel)]="test"/>
```

Comment: that didn't work for me and that why for setting value trying any alternative approach

Comment: did you try with the [] ? in your question you have with without the brackets and using {{}}

Comment: like i said ngmodel is already being used by another task and that to it is dynamic model  [(ngModel)]="Edit[dataname]" i cant set value to this right

Comment: if you want to set a value in the text without using anything else but the input field without using [(ngModel)] i dont think it can be done since ngModel is what makes the 2 way binding for us. If you can use like a button or something else then sure. Like an event or a button or something else @Dexter

Comment: i found a way using the template reference and  view child i can set value

Comment: Yeah you can do it that way, you can't just do it without using something else in the input directly that is not the ngModel

Answer (score 0):

**using reference variable #inp**

```
  OnInputClick(inp:any){   }//Typesctipt
```

```html
<input id="{{data.name}}" value="{{data.name}}"  type="{{data.type}}" #inp class="form-control">
<button (click)="OnInputClick(inp.value)">Input</button>
```

Comment: the fields are dynamic and i am not getting values i m setting the value

Answer (score 0):

use keyup to capture event and store in .ts

```
 <input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

in .ts

> "event.target.value"

have value entered by user , use it as you want

```
values ='' // provide a default value here whatever you want
onKey(event: any) { 
    this.values += event.target.value;
  }
```

Comment: have to set value please refer to my  question

Comment: thats why defined values = "your value " in .ts

Comment: you can use {{values}} in your html displaying its result , if you want to display this in your input tag then there are attributes  for input tag like [value] where you can assign this variable to display some value in input field. eg 
[value]= "values"  // [value] an attribute and values a var defined in .ts.

Answer (score 0):

As per then Angular Document you can use the following code

```
<input  [value]="data.name" (input)="data.name=$event.target.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an [on blur event](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#on-blur)

This updates the value whenever the user leaves the input field you started to edit.

**example.html:**

```
<input #tsVarName (blur)="addBlurVal(tsVarName.value)" >
```

**example.ts**

```
export class example {
    globalVal = "";

    addBlurVal(localVar) {
         this.globalVal = localVal;
    }
 }
```